# ReactJS/Axios: Unhandled Rejection (Error): Request failed with status code 500

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios

I'm creating a job board with a React frontend and a Flask backend. When I try to call the Flask backed, I get an Unhandled Rejection (Error): Request failed with status code 500. Some other details:

1. I get a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable error from the Flask backend. I think that I'm not sending request parameters, but I can't figure out why.
2. The backend works with Postman.
3. getJoblisting seems to clear out the states from the inputs

Here's my React code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

function cardLayout(props, i)
{
    return(
        <div key={i}>
            <p>{props.description}</p>
        </div>
    )

}//cardLayout

function Jobcard(props)
{
    let job_reports = props.reports;

    let reports_length = 0;
    let json_reports = [];

    if (typeof job_listings !== 'undefined')
    {
        json_reports=JSON.parse(job_reports);
        reports_length = json_reports.length;
    }//if not undefined

    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < reports_length; i++) {
        rows.push( cardLayout(json_reports[i], i));
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {rows}
        </div>
    );
}//function Jobrow

class JobSearch extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state =
            {
                q: null,
                l: null,
                ip: null,
                status: "Look for your dream job"
            };
        //bind to make `this` work in the callback
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.getJobListing = this.getJobListing.bind(this);
     }

  handleChange = event => {
      this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  getJobListing()
  {
      this.setState({
          status: "Searching...",
      });

      //send to server
      let json_req = {"q": this.state.q, "l": this.state.l, "ip": this.state.ip};

      axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_JOB_BOARD_API, json_req)
          .then(res => {
              this.setState({
                  status: Jobcard(res.data)
              });
          }) //axios
  }//getJobListing

  render()
  {
    let job_report;
    job_report = this.state.status;

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="q"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input
                type="text"
                name="q"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input
                type="text"
                name="ip"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <button
                    onClick={this.getJobListing}
                    >
                    SUBMIT
                </button>
            </div>
            <div>
                { job_report }
            </div>
      </div>
        )
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
    <JobSearch />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

Error message

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Request failed with status code 500

getJobListing
src/index.js:69

  66 | //send to server
  67 | let json_req = {"q": this.state.q, "l": this.state.l, "ip": this.state.ip};
  68 | 
> 69 | axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_JOB_BOARD_API, json_req)
     | ^  70 |     .then(res => {
  71 |         this.setState({
  72 |             status: Jobcard(res.data)
```

Comment: What's the Flask error you get? A 500 indicates that Flask generated an exception. You'll get a 400 if you're giving it incorrect/incomplete data.

Comment: I get a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable error. It seems like I'm not passing any parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending `null` values to your API while it expects strings, dictionaries or lists as it seems you are trying to access their individual elements (that's what `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` means).

You probably get this error when you leave one or more of the fields empty. They'll then be `null` as that's how you initialise them.

Solution is to either give `q`, `l` and `ip` non-null values before you send them to the API or ignore `null` values in your API e.g.

```py
data = request.get_json()

if data['q']:
    # do something useful only if q is not None
```

Comment: Yes, that's where I think I'm having an issue. I pass the inputs as the parameters with this line:
`let json_req = {"q": this.state.q, "l": this.state.l, "ip": this.state.ip};`
But it doesn't seem that it's being sent to the API with Axios.

Comment: Are you making sure that all values are filled in when you press `Submit`? You'll get a 500 error even if you submit one empty value. Can you share your API code as well?